# IBus 1.5 seems fail in supporting Ubuntu 18?

Tags: ibus, language-support

I need IBus to type Vietnamese and Japanese so I installed engine `ibus-bamboo` and `ibus-mozc` for that need. However, none of engines actually work (even `ibus-unikey` is default engine for Vietnamese also fails). So far this is what I have:

## Specification

Desktop Environment: GNOME
Ubuntu: 18
IBus: 1.5

## What I did

1. Installed ibus, ibus-bamboo, ibus-mozc from apt / offical Ubuntu repo.
2. Added Bamboo and Mozc from `ibus-setup`
3. Followed guide of [Bamboo engine](https://github.com/BambooEngine/ibus-bamboo/wiki/Kh%C3%B4ng-g%C3%B5-%C4%91%C6%B0%E1%BB%A3c-ti%E1%BA%BFng-vi%E1%BB%87t-tr%C3%AAn-ph%E1%BA%A7n-m%E1%BB%81m-%60abc-xyz%60) and [IBus troubleshooting](https://github.com/ibus/ibus/wiki/FAQ).

[Update]
I've also used the GUI setting, this is my first solution. I let the `Manage Installed Languages` install Vietnamese which give me `ibus-unikey`. But it didn't work so I thought it broke. Then I installed `ibus-bamboo` and the result is the same so I install Japanese also via MIL and got Mozc. That's where I concluded this might be error from ibus.
[image: Setup via GUI setting]

### Expectation and reality

IBus supposes to type out on Firefox and other GUI applications. Any where have input fields. But in reality, search bar is the only place IBus can work. I've reported [this problem to the repo](https://github.com/ibus/ibus/issues/2125). And now I looking for a solution, alternative or fixing, because all I need is an IME that can help me to type both Vietnamese and Japanese out.

[Update 5-Sep-2019]
I've reinstalled `ibus` and its engines but nothing has changed. I also tried it with new user account (which means it comes with clean profile and setting) but no progress. I still cannot type Vietnamese or Japanese. I will install Xubuntu in place of Ubuntu and see whether problem is solved or not.

[Update same-day but after tried live-cd of xubuntu]
I tried Xubuntu by Live-CD and install ibus with the same IME engines like I did on Ubuntu. The results is... funny. Only mousepad (or that's what it called), a kind of build-in text editor can use IME the rest, is no-go. (Xubuntu is only use difference DE from Ubuntu, as far as I know, so this can't be DE fault.)

[Update 9-Sep-2019] Someone suggest me that it may be cause by `snap`. So I decided to remove it but nothing thing seems to be better. **Krita** can use ibus ok!

Comment: You should not use `ibus-setup` on Ubuntu with GNOME. Add the sources via _Settings -> Region & Language -> Input Sources_ instead.

Comment: I did setup it once but no use. Let me update my question.

Comment: Did you remove it again? In that case follow-up questions are pointless, I suppose. Your general suspicion, that IBus doesn't work on Ubuntu 18.04 is of course not the case. Many users use it every day.

Comment: But I don't really know how to debug Linux so pointing directly to the cause is likely impossible (even though I really want to make clear of this). For now, all I can do is describe what I've experience while using it.

Comment: I didn't suggest that you should point directly to the cause - in that case you would have been able to fix it yourself and wouldn't have needed to post here. But when asking for help here, you should describe as detailed as possible what you did (your description above is ok) and then be open for trying suggestions which people may post.

Comment: Uhm, I'm opening for suggestions. But if my words are harsh then I'm sorry because I'm not pretty well with English emotion expression (didn't read literarure that much). Anyway, do you have other suggestion because I've tried all of those but still no-good.

Comment: It was probably "I did setup it once but no use" which made me jump at conclusions. Anyway, two things: 1. Click the _Manage Installed Languages_ button and make sure that IBus is the selected input method system. 2. Click the _Options_ button along with "Input Sources" and make sure that the "Use the same source for all windows" option is selected.

Comment: After I'd followed you advice, I tried new DE (Xubuntu) but I still cannot type Vi or Ja.

Comment: Wondering if you miss something trivial. When you switch to Mozc, it defaults to _Direct input_, so you need to select _Input Mode_ and choose e.g. _Hiragana_ to start inputting Japanese characters. (I know nothing about Bamboo, but there may be some similar thing you need to know to be able to use that input method.)

Comment: I used Mozc (or similar thing) in Windows so I don't think I made those mistakes. As far as I've seen, Bamboo and Mozc have the same way to use in Windows.

Comment: I wouldn't assume that there are no differences between the Linux Mozc client and the Windows ditto. You wouldn't be the first to stumble on that issue.

Comment: But I have clicked on every buttons in the menu from icon at the corner. From `input mode` to `tool` and I can said GUI is pretty similar to Window. I just don't know whether difference in engine (below GUI). Do I missing any packages that the system doesn't warn me? (That is my doubt at the moment)

Comment: Oh I forgot, I think I know it work most the same Windows but cause the way it work on search bar (super-key and start typing) is similar with windows (for Mozc). But no where else in Ubuntu could work like that. (I wrote it in **Expectation and reality** once)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally fixed the problem. I think the main reason is caused by `snapd` packages.

1. Reinstall Ubuntu 19
2. Remove `snapd`: `sudo apt autoremove --purge snapd`
3. Install ibus engines. (in my case, it is `ibus-bamboo` and `ibus-mozc`)